# Allow user to completely delete account (and data), not just cancel it

Tags: 7, users

I want users to provide option to cancel their own account. I know this is supported in D7, and I am using that only. But I want it in a manner that, when a user selects to cancel that account, all of his content and comments should be deleted. Right now, it is just blocking the user account, and keeping his all content.

If I grant user the permission "Select method for cancelling own account", then he may selects the option to retain his content upon cancellation, which I don't want.

So is there any way that when user cancels his account, cancellation method will delete the user account completely, without asking user to select from options.

-- Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself. It is under: `Configuration-> Account Settings-> When cancelling a user account` section.